# Creating backup and auto-save files that are not hidden

Tags: auto-save, backup

I use the following code for backup and auto-save files:

```
(setq delete-old-versions -1)
(setq version-control t)
(setq vc-make-backup-files t)
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "h:/saves")))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms '((".*" "~/.auto-save-list/" t)))
```

The backup files created are all hidden. I would like to change that so that they are made in a non-hidden format.

An example is: `!drive_c!home!.emacs.d!recentf.~2~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by the files being "hidden"? Hidden where, how?

You can specify the file names you want for backup files, if something is causing them to be somehow "hidden" based on their names (use different names). See the Emacs manual, node [Backup Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html).

And if you're talking about auto-save files, then see node [Auto Save Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html).

Backup files and auto-save files are not the same thing.

---

**Update after a comment by OP**

If this is about **Dired** hiding files, please specify just what you mean by hiding.

1. If this is about hiding by *omitting*, then customize option **`dired-omit-files`**.  `C-h v` tells us:

> **`dired-omit-files`** is a variable defined in `dired-x.el`.
>
> Its value is `"^\\.?#\\|^\\.$\\|^\\.\\.$"`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Filenames matching this regexp will not be displayed.
>
> This only has effect when `dired-omit-mode` is `t`.  See interactive function
> `dired-omit-mode` (`C-x M-o`) and variable
> `dired-omit-extensions`.  The default is to omit  `.`, `..`, auto-save
> files and lock files.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Note that my value of this option includes auto-save files (which end in `#`).

If this is about Dired showing **ignored** files differently, then customize option `completion-ignored-extensions`. `C-h v dired-ignored-face` tells us:

> **`dired-ignored-face`** is a variable defined in `dired.el`.
>
> Its value is `dired-ignored`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Face name used for files suffixed with `completion-ignored-extensions`.

And `C-h v completion-ignored-extensions` tells us this:

> **`completion-ignored-extensions`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is shown below.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Completion ignores file names ending in any string in this list.
>
> It does not ignore them if all possible completions end in one of
> these strings or when displaying a list of completions.
> It ignores directory names if they match any string in this list which
> ends in a slash.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Value:
>
> ```
> (".o" "~" ".bin" ".bak" ".obj" ".map" ".ico" ".pif" ".lnk" ".a" ".ln"
>  ".blg" ".bbl" ".dll" ".drv" ".vxd" ".386" ".elc" ".lof" ".glo" ".idx"
>  ".lot" ".svn/" ".hg/" ".git/" ".bzr/" "CVS/" "_darcs/" "_MTN/" ".fmt"
>  ".tfm" ".class" ".fas" ".lib" ".mem" ".x86f" ".sparcf" ".dfsl" ".pfsl"
>  ".d64fsl" ".p64fsl" ".lx64fsl" ".lx32fsl" ".dx64fsl" ".dx32fsl"
>  ".fx64fsl" ".fx32fsl" ".sx64fsl" ".sx32fsl" ".wx64fsl" ".wx32fsl"
>  ".fasl" ".ufsl" ".fsl" ".dxl" ".lo" ".la" ".gmo" ".mo" ".toc" ".aux"
>  ".cp" ".fn" ".ky" ".pg" ".tp" ".vr" ".cps" ".fns" ".kys" ".pgs" ".tps"
>  ".vrs" ".pyc" ".pyo")
> ```

Your current value is likely different from mine.  Notice that mine includes **`"~"`**, which means that backup files are highlighted as being "ignored" files.

Comment: I mean that they are treated as hidden files in Dired.

Comment: Put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own.

Comment: I have customized `completion-ignored-extensions` by removing `~` and the now files are not longer "hidden".

Comment: It would probably help others if you clarify what you mean by "hidden" in the question - e.g., describe the visual effect of a "hidden" file. In the case of omission the file is not listed; in the case of being "ignored" it is just highlighted differently.